# Is =! a declaration and is that why this alternating conditional works?

Tags: php

I have a terrible confession. I've been using variations of the below for ages.

```
for($x=0;10>$x;++$x){
    echo '<li style="color:#'.(($c=!$c)? "fff":"eee").'">example $x</li>";
}
```

My dilemma is that I don't entirely understand how it works. I know that $c=!$c makes the ternary conditional alternate, but I don't understand how. Googling "php =!" and the likes yields nothing helpful (no surprise given the query).

!= is an operator, but this uses =!

Is this a ternary conditional declaration? If so, how does this one work? I understand the general conditional declarations, but not this one... assuming it even is one.

Any answer or link to documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It _doesn't_ work, because you messed up your quotes.

Comment: `$c=!$c` is valid, assigning to `$c` to the value of  `not $c`, typically used to toggle a Boolean value; in this case being used to alternate the colour of successive elements

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit He's talking about the `$c=!$c` not about whether his code is working or not. The quotes could be a typo.

Comment: Fixed the quote, because it caused confusion. Normally I wouldn't do this in a question, but in this case, the question clearly isn't about a syntax error, so it seems it's just a typo.

Comment: Thank you, GolezTrol. Definitely just a typo. I'm not trying to fix any code, just understand it properly since I picked it up a long while back, but was never completely sure I knew what was happening. Just trying to learn :)  So, thank you, also, Mark Baker.

Comment: Thank you to all the below who chimed in!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are two separate operators. You should read it as

```
$c = !$c;
```

In other words, assign the result of the expression `!$c` back to the variable `$c`. So indeed, it toggles the value of `$c`.

Additionally, an assignment like this also returns the assigned value, so you can evaluate it immediately. So in words, the expression `($c=!$c)? "fff":"eee"` says:

> "Invert the value of $c. If the new value is true, return 'fff', otherwise return 'eee'."

Comment: Thank you! That's a bit more embarrassingly simply than I thought. I was just looking at it totally wrong. Clear spacing made it... clear. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

It's not an operator, it just needs better spacing:

```
$x = !$x;
```

it's just inverting the value.

Answer (score 0):

`=!` is not an operator. It is *two*: `=` means assignment, and `!` means negation.

If `$c` is `true`, then `!$c` is `false` (and vice versa).

And assignments evaluate to their new value.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting $c to be not itself. So if $c == true you are saying $c = not true, I.e. false which will also count as false for the ternary.
Next iteration you set $c = not false I.e. true and so on.